# Finding progression of category purchases

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

If I had a table as such:

[image]

How do I structure a SQL (mysql or redshift) to show a progression of what customers purchased into their subsequent purchases of a new category?  like:

[image]

Where I use the first_time_customer flag to define if a parent_category is NEW (or first time buyer of this category) and progression_category defines the next categories being purchased (purchased is defined as customers buying the same progression of categories from new until their last purchase).   Notice that customer A bought 2 different categories, and that drives the subsequent 4 rows at the end.    The actual table is 90 million rows.

Comment: does parent_category comes from another table?

Comment: No, parent_category was just a parent roll up of the first category.  Perhaps a month or date column in the second image would help describe the intended result better

Comment: You need to explain the logic.  It is not clear.  How is "33" calculated?  Is `first_time_customer` being used?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, that was sloppy first post.  Edited with better visual and logic